# dask dataframe set_index throws error

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask dataframe created from parquet file on HDFS.
When creating setting index using api: set_index, it fails with below error.

> File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py", line 64, in set_index
>       divisions, sizes, mins, maxes = base.compute(divisions, sizes, mins, maxes)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 206, in compute
>       results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1949, in get
>       results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1391, in gather
>       asynchronous=asynchronous)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 561, in sync
>       return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 241, in sync
>       six.reraise(*error[0])
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 229, in f
>       result[0] = yield make_coro()
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
>       raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>     File "", line 4, in raise_exc_info
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1063, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1269, in _gather
>       traceback)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>     File "/ebs/d1/agent/conda/envs/py361/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py", line 144, in _read_parquet_row_group
>       open=open, assign=views, scheme=scheme)
>   TypeError: read_row_group_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scheme'

Can some one point me to the reason of this error and how to fix it.

Comment: The issue resolved by downgrading dask to 0.15.3 from 0.15.4 and distributed to 1.19.1 from 1.19.2.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Upgrade fastparquet to version 0.1.3.

#### Details

Dask 0.15.4, used for your example, includes [this commit](https://github.com/dask/dask/commit/68d8c955159f82ec6456e887010c9ad93a44d8b4#diff-410a8a0995091d42fbbbc5a50efda3ae), which adds the argument `scheme` to `read_row_group_file()`. This throws an error for fastparquet versions before 0.1.3.